# Who is Sayidat Nisaa al aalamin?

Tags: tafseer

Note: the approximate meaning of "Sayidat Nisaa' al aalamin" can be considered as the following English translation:

**The lady (the best lady) of the ladies of the worlds.**

My question is that:

> من هي سيدة نساء العالمين: العذراء مريم او فاطمة الزهراء؟
>    / Who is Sayidat Nisaa' al aalamin? Al-Ozra' Maryam or Fatimah a-Zahra?

I was in a place where they were arguing about that.

I guess it's a verse in Quran:

> قال تعالى: واذ قالت الملائكة يا مريم ان الله اصطفاك وطهرك واصطفاك على نساء العالمين يا مريم اقنتي لربك واسجدي واركعي مع الراكعين ذلك من انباء الغيب نوحيه  اليك وما كنت لديهم اذ يلقون اقلامهم ايهم يكفل مريم وما كنت لديهم اذ يختصمون.
>    /
>   3:42

So, who is her (Sayidat Nisaa al aalamin)?

Comment: @Mustaghees. Google translate does not work with Arabic, and certainly not with Qur'anic and Classical Arabic. There are, however, plenty of English translations of the Qur'an that you can easily look up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                                    In the Name of Allah
```

Briefly speaking:

First of all, in regard to the Surah Al-i-Imran:42 which says

> And [mention] when the angels said, "O Mary, indeed Allah has chosen
>   you and purified you and chosen you above the women of the worlds.
>   (42)
>
> وَإِذْ قَالَتِ الْمَلَائِكَةُ يَا مَرْيَمُ إِنَّ اللَّـهَ اصْطَفَاكِ
>   وَطَهَّرَكِ وَاصْطَفَاكِ عَلَىٰ نِسَاءِ الْعَالَمِينَ ﴿٤٢

The interpretation or the phrase of “Seyyedate-Nesaa’-Al-Alamin is not available directly in the holy Quran.

On the other hand, based on that phrase "و اصطفاک علی نساء العالمین" or “Allah has chosen you and purified you and chosen you above the women of the worlds” , so the meaning of the mentioned verse is that Allah chose her (Hazrat Maryam) between her era’s women, but Hazrat Fatimah-a-Zahra is considered as Seyyedate-Nesaa’-Al-Alamin based on the traditions.

It is quoted that Mofzal said I told Imam Sadiq (a.s.):

> Inform me regarding the speech of the Prophet (peace be upon him and
>   his family) concerning Hazrat Fatimah “definitely she is the greatest
>   of the worlds women”, is she the greatest lady of her period? He
>   replied: this position is for Hazrat Maryam, that she was the greatest
>   lady between the ladies (women) of her period, but Hazrat Fatimah is
>   considered as the lord (master) and the leader of the ladies of across
>   the existence universe since the start to the end.

For more info. refer to ( [this site](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa13472) ) (In Arabic)

**References:**

[www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa13472)

[tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/3:42)

Answer (score 2):

There isn’t phrase of “Sayidat Nisaa al aalamin” in Quran, directly. The verse you asked exist in Surat 'Āli `Imrān (verse 42) which have “Nisaa al aalamin”:

> "إِذْ قالَتِ الْمَلائِکَةُ یا مَرْیَمُ إِنَّ اللَّهَ اصْطَفاکِ وَ
>   طَهَّرَکِ وَ اصْطَفاکِ عَلى‏ نِساءِ الْعالَمین‏"
>
> And [mention] when the angels said, "O Mary, indeed Allah has chosen
>   you and purified you and chosen you above the women of the worlds.

It means Allah has chosen Maryam between her contemporary women for being mother of Masih while she was maiden. But according to our narratives and hadiths, hazrat Zahra is “sayidat” of all women of the world  which isn’t limited to her contemporary women.

“Sayidat Nisaa al aalamin” is a epithet which prophet Muhammad (pbuh) used to call hazrat Zahra by, for example:

> نزل ملک من السماء فاستأذن اللَّه أن یسلّم علىّ، فبشّرنى انّ فاطمه سیده
>   نساء اهل الجنّه»
>
> "An angel was sent and were allowed by God to sallam me, he gives me
>   enunciation that Fatemeh is “Sayidat Nisaa al  aalamin””( **al-Hâkim's
>   Mustadrak , volume3 , page151**)
>
> «یا فاطمه! الاترضین ان تکونى سیده نساء العالمین»
>
> “Fatemeh…would’t you consent to be  “Sayidat Nisaa al aalamin””(
>   **Sahih Muslim, volume 3 ,  page 158**)
>
> «و امّا ابنتى فاطمه فانّها سیده نساء العالمین…»
>
> “But my daughter Fatimah, she is “Sayidat Nisaa al aalamin””( **Bihār
>   al-Anwār ,volume 43, page 172**)

And extra…

Imam al-Sadiq in the answer of mafzal ‘s question about phrase of prophet to hazrat fatemeh (“Sayidat Nisaa al aalamin”)said:

“Maryam was great woman between  her contemporary women but hazrat fateme is great woman between all women of the world from beginning to end…”( **Ma'ani al-akhbar written by al-Shaykh al-Saduq ,page 107**)

In addition, Such questions exist in Quran about excellence of Bani Isra'il on others (Surat Al-Baqarah, verse 47.122) and excellence of Al Ibrahim and Al Imran on others in the world (Surat 'Ali `Imran,verse 33),too.

Which in all of them like the verse you asked, excellence is relative and limited to their time.